# how can I set the width of this div (chart__amount__item) to the data that I fetched from the JSON file using reactjs inline style?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to set the width of the div with the class of "chart__amount__item" to the value that I fetched from the JSON file using react inline style, the JSON file returns an array of numbers.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

const TheChart = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState([]);
  const getData = () => {
    fetch("data.json", {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
        setAmount(data);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => getData(), []);
  return (
    <div className="chart">
      <h2 className="chart__title"> Spending - Last 7 days</h2>
      <div className="chart__amount">
        {data &&
          data.length > 0 &&
          data.map((item, index) => (
            <div
              className="chart__amount__item"
              key={index}
              style={{ width: "item.amount/7" }}
            ></div>
          ))}
      </div>
      <div className="chart__days">
        {data &&
          data.length > 0 &&
          data.map((item, index) => (
            <div key={index} className="chart__day__item">
              {item.day}
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TheChart;
```

using `{{width: 'item.amount/7'}}` won't work.

Comment: did you try without the double quotes? i.e. `style={{ width: item.amount/7 }}`

Comment: yup, nothing shows up.

Comment: please share a sample item from `data.json`

Comment: [
  {
    "day": "mon",
    "amount": 17.45
  },
  {
    "day": "tue",
    "amount": 34.91
  },
  {
    "day": "wed",
    "amount": 52.36
  },
  {
    "day": "thu",
    "amount": 31.07
  },
  {
    "day": "fri",
    "amount": 23.39
  },
  {
    "day": "sat",
    "amount": 43.28
  },
  {
    "day": "sun",
    "amount": 25.48
  }
]